# Ethernet Shield on Arduino Mini

Tags: shields, ethernet, atmega328

I would like to connect my custom-made Arduino with an Ethernet shield but I'm not so sure I can.

### The problem

My board is using the design from the Arduino Mini which lacks the `ATmega16U2` which does the USB-to-serial conversion and adds the `ICSP` pins. I think you get the point... I have only the `ATmega328P` on the board. Nothing else.

Is it even possible to work my way around it without adding the `ATmega16U2`? I can't find the chip anywhere on Ebay.

Comment: Are you using an IEthernet shield (using a W5200, W5500 or such like), or do you mean a generic Ethernet shield? Your title and body are inconsistent. Not that important, but a little confusing :-)

Comment: Im using the shield with the W5500. Is there any difference with the other chips?

Comment: There may be some differences, but I was just trying to clarify whether the "IEthernet", in your title, was a typo or not. I understand now, that it wasn't :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just connect the pins used on the shield the the corresponding pins on your custom board. Check the [Schematic](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-ethernet-shield-06-schematic.pdf) to see what pins are used for what (and which can be left unconnected)

<strike>The only thing you need to lookout for is, that the ethernets shield seems to require 3.3v</strike> (the shield has it's own 3.3v regulator, so you only need to connect 5v)

That 16u2 doesn't do anything but usb-to-serial. It's not needed for the ethernet shield.

The ISP header is just 5v, GND, and the 3 SPI pins and reset. But those SPI pins are also broken out to the pins 11, 12 and 13.

Comment: So basicaly im just using the pins 11, 12 and 13 for the shield?

Comment: Indeed those, and 10 for the ChipSelect (SS). Pin 4, if you want to use the SD card functionality. See my edit concerning the 3.3v.